# Naming the sorting algorithm. Is it QuickSort?

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

For this sorting algorithm I wrote, I have two questions:

1.When I range fill a vector `[max-num, 0]` (worst-case scenario) I get a result way better than `O(n^2)`. (I'm not even sure if I even wrote a quicksort anymore).

2.When I mix up the range, ex: I fill the unsorted vector `[0, max-num/2]` then `[max-num/2, 0]`, weirdly enough it runs with crashing up to numbers 900,000 but crashes right after.

```
template<class writeIter>
void quicksort(writeIter begin, writeIter end)
{
if (begin!= end) {
    int diff = end-begin;
    if (diff > 2) {

        writeIter pivot = ((end-begin) / 2) + begin;
        writeIter itFirst = begin;
        writeIter itSecnd = end-1;
        auto pivotVal = *pivot;

        swap(*pivot, *(end-1));
        while (itFirst < itSecnd) {
            if (*itFirst > pivotVal) {
                while (*itSecnd > pivotVal && itSecnd > itFirst) --itSecnd;
                if (itSecnd > itFirst)
                    swap(*itFirst, *itSecnd);
            }
            ++itFirst;
        }
        swap(*itSecnd, *(end-1));

        quicksort(begin, itSecnd);
        quicksort(itSecnd, end);
    }
    else if (diff  == 2)
        if (*begin > *(begin+1))
            swap(*begin, *(begin+1));
 }
}
```

Comment: You have *three* questions. The answer to the first is 'yes', modulo bugs.

Comment: You probably have a stack overflow. The algorithm will select a very bad pivot (close to the maximum) each time and divide the range into extremely uneven parts. This is bad for quicksort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes， it's the naive quick sort. But you choose the middle element instead of the last element as your pivot.

1. When you fill a vector [max-num, 0], it's actually **not the
   worst-case scenario** at all. Because each time you choose the
   middle element as the pivot, you divide the vector into two parts
   with almost the same size, so the time complexity is O(nlogn).
2. However, when you fill the unsorted vector [0, max-num/2] then [max-num/2, 0], it's the worst-case for you algorithm as you divide the vector into two parts with one extremely long and one extremely short. So the time complexity is O(n^2).

To gain a better performance on almost all vectors, you can:

- pick a random element as your pivot
- pick three random elements and choose the second largest one
- when the size of vector is small enough, e.g., smaller than 10, apply insert sort on it
- to deal with the situation that all elements are close to each other, you can do some extra work before recursively sorting subvectors to skip the elements equal to the pivot

Comment: I changed choosing the pivot to a random position and it outperforms std::sort if I do the mix range I mentioned above. Thanks for helpful tips :).

Comment: Also that title is catastrophic! It was really late so I am not even sure if I was awake when I asked the question.